# Azure B2C: Log reasons tokens are invalidated

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My application uses Azure B2C to authenticate users (Custom policies). Some users are often (some times several times a day) asked to re-authenticate when navigating the website (built with react). But some are not, and never have to re-authenticate (refresh token mechanism working as expected). Token management is done using [microsoft MSAL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-javascript-auth-code-react) without any fancy customization.

My question is: how can I log/know (probably directly on the Azure B2C portal) the reasons why B2C invalidates the tokens in the first place? Is there such a feature on the Azure portal?

Answer (score 1):

In JS apps, the **refresh token** is [fixed at 24hrs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#token-lifetime-behavior).

The AAD B2C **web app session cookie** (fallback after RT expires), has a maximum [length of 24hrs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior).

AAD B2C doesn't invalidate refresh tokens, they can only expire. Refresh tokens are only invalidated if your application/service explicitly calls the refresh token revocation [Graph API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

In your case, it is extremely likely that users are using the app after 24hrs of last logging in.

You can offer [Keep-Me-Signed-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi) option so users can have a long lived session cookie.